# Determining field lines of three-dimensional vector fields

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

This has been a long time for me and my analysis reference is pretty abstract.

> Could anybody show me again how to calculate the vector field lines
>   for $F(x)=(y-z, z-x, x-y)$?

I know I have to make the differential equation and that the solution will be circles (when I plot it), but I forgot exactly which equation to make. I will be able to solve it of course, just reminding me the equation to solve is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want curves such that the vector field is tangent to the curve at any point. In other words, you want functions $\gamma:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^3$ such that $\gamma'(t) = F(\gamma(t))$. Separating out the three component functions of $\gamma$, this is a system of homogenous, linear, first order differential equations with constant coefficients. Which is to say, we may write it using matrix multiplication in the following form:
$$
\gamma'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}\gamma(t)
$$
Systems like this will have solutions of the form $e^{\lambda t}v$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the above matrix, and $v$ is a corresponding eigenvector. And of course, any linear combination of such solutions is also a solution.

So we solve for the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the above matrix. They turn out to be
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline\text{Eigenvalue}& \text{Eigenvector}\\
\hline 0 & (1, 1, 1)^T\\
i\sqrt3 & (1-i\sqrt3, 1+i\sqrt3, -2)^T\\
-i\sqrt3 & (1+i\sqrt3, 1-\sqrt3, -2)^T\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
A keen eye will spot that an eigenvalue of $0$ means the corresponding eigenvector doesn't change as time goes by (in other words, that's the axis of rotation), while a conjugate pair of pure imaginary eigenvalues corresponds to pure rotation.

If you pick any vector $u\in \Bbb R^3$, and decompose it into a linear combination $a\cdot u_1 + b\cdot u_2 + c\cdot u_3$ of these three eigenvectors, then the field line that goes through $u$ will be given by
$$
a\cdot u_1 + b\cdot e^{i\sqrt3t}u_2 + c\cdot e^{-i\sqrt3t}u_3
$$
One can, of course, get rid of any and all mention of complex numbers here by replacing it with trigonometry, but I don't think that it makes the solution any nicer.

Comment: Thanks man, amazing thorough explanation! Only question; what is the easy way to now show that these lines are circles x^2+y^2+z^2 = c?

Comment: @Tumke Take $a\cdot u_1 + b\cdot e^{i\sqrt3t}u_2 + c\cdot e^{-i\sqrt3t}u_3$, express it in the standard basis, and calculate the time derivative of $x^2+y^2+z^2$. You will get $0$, which means that the solution curve always moves on a fixed sphere. If you want to show that it is a _circle_, you will also have to show that in addition to being constrained to a sphere, it is also constrained to a plane. Think about what that plane might be, and how you would prove that the curve always lies in that plane. Again it's about finding a relevant real-valued function of $x, y, z$ and differentiating.

Comment: Ill work on this, thanks!

Comment: That would be x+y+z if I see it correctly

Comment: @Tumke Yup, that's right. The normal planes of the rotational axis.